# push items into an array then reverse array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, reverse

I've created an array that I now want to reverse. The array should display every number from the number specified down to 0.

I've tried using the `reverse()` method in various ways but it either misses out every other number in the array or returns nothing at all?

In the code below the `else if` statement is where the array wants reversing.

Is there a way to use the `reverse()` method on the array here or an alternative way to do this?

Thanks

```
function myFunc() {

  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  var counter = [];
  var start = 0;
    if (x > 40) { 
      start = 40;
      } else { 
      start = 0; }

  for (var i = start; i < x; i++) {
    if (x > 40 && i % 2 == 1) {
        counter.push(i);
    } else if (x < 40) {
        counter.push(i).reverse(); //reverse here returns nothing
        counter.reverse();         //reverse here returns every other number only 
    }
  }

   return counter + ',' + x;

}

 console.log(myFunc())
```

Comment: why you are not using counter.reverse and then push

Comment: Watch out the [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns **the new length of the array**, not the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
......
for (var i = start; i < x; i++) {
    if ((x > 40 && i % 2 == 1) || x < 40) {
        counter.push(i);
    }
}

if(x<40)
    counter.reverse(); 

return counter; 
}
```

Should work like this.. (unless I misunderstood your problem?)

Answer (score 0):

> I've created an array that I now want to reverse. The array should display every number from the number specified down to 0.

If this is the problem, then you can solve it easier like this:

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
var counter = [];
var end = (x > 40 ? 40 : 0);
while (end <= x) {
    counter.push(x);
    --x;
}
return counter;
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/3LvwZ/)

Your code however does something else, but you can adjust it like:

```
while (end <= x) {
    if ( ((40 < x) && (1 == x % 2)) || (40 > x)) {
        counter.push(x);
    }
    --x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/aLUfh/2/

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
var counter = [];

for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    counter.push(i);
}

counter.reverse();
$('#Xis').html(x);
$('#outcome').html(counter + ',' + x);
```